# Remove Git folder Added files via upload

Tags: git, github

I add to my repository a folder with my school computer and now I want to delete it but this folder isn't on my local repository, how can I remove this folder?

I tried to download the folder and added to my local folder and do:

```
git rm -r <Folder>
fatal: pathspec '<Folder> did not match any files
```

Or

```
git rm --cached <Folder>
```

but same result

Answer (score 1):

You should simply be able to remove it from your file explorer (assuming you have added that folder in a local clone of your repo, on your school computer).

Git is not involved since the folder is not tracked.